# Typescript - creating a type where the keys come from a pre-existing type - but not required

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

Title might be a bit confusing, so let's try and explain better.

Say I have a type called `Stage`.

```
type Stage = 'beta' | 'gamma' | 'prod';
```

I want to create a new type where the keys can only be from `Stage` - but I don't want to require all possible keys of `Stage` to be keys on the created object.

For example, something like this would be fine:

```
const obj: NewVal = {
    beta: value,
    prod: value2,
};
```

I have tried using the following:

```
type NewVal = Record<Stage, string>;

type NewVal = { [key in Stage]: string };
```

but both of those options require all keys of `Stage` to be present on the object. Using `Partial` seems to work, but it introduces more issues when dealing with possible `undefined` values, so I'd rather not deal with it.

Is there some way to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

Would

```
type NewVal = { [key in Stage]?: string };
```

address your issues?  Or is that too close to `Partial`?